# VB changing domain name of PC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vbscript, vb6

I wonder if there is way to change Domain on computer by using Visual Basic or VB Script. I have to nanualy transfer over 100 PC to another domain. By running application which would automaticaly change domain on computer would be useful.

Comment: See `wmic computersystem call /?`. This is an alias for win32_computersystem.

Comment: This is an example wmic command that queries the eventlogs of computers listed in computername.txt. `wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\EventLog.html" /failfast:on PATH Win32_NTLogEvent where  (EventIDentifier=42 or eventidentifier=1003) get /format:hform`

Comment: Here's some sample code from the docs for Join (which you need to read) Example Code [VBScript]
The following VBScript example joins a computer to a domain and creates the computer's account in Active Directory. 

Const JOIN_DOMAIN             = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE             = 2
Const ACCT_DELETE             = 4
Const WIN9X_UPGRADE           = 16
Const DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED   = 32
Const JOIN_UNSECURE           = 64
Const MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128
Const DEFERRED_SPN_SET        = 256
Const INSTALL_INVOCATION      = 262144
strDomain   = "FABRIKAM"
strPassword = "ls4k5ywA"

Comment: strUser     = "shenalan"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = _
    GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" _
    & strComputer & "'")
ReturnValue = objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup(strDomain, _
    strPassword, _
    strDomain & "\" & strUser, _
    NULL, _
    JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)

Comment: Please refrain from posting code in comment area, its not pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class, e.g. in VBScript:

```
Const JOIN_DOMAIN = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE = 2

domain   = "DOMAIN"
username = "user"
password = "pass"
ou       = Null  'create the computer object in the default location

Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!" _
          & "//./root/cimv2")

Set computer = wmi.Get("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" & net.ComputerName & "'")
result = computer.JoinDomainOrWorkgroup(domain, password, _
         domain & "\" & username, ou, JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)
If result <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Domain join failed (" & result & ")."
  WScript.Quit result
End If

For Each computer In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
  computer.Reboot
Next
```

or you could shell out to the [`netdom`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217.aspx) command:

```
netdom join %COMPUTERNAME% /domain:DOMAIN /userd:DOMAIN\USER /passwordd:PASS
shutdown -r -t 0
```